# Java Array Index Out of Bound

Tags: java

I have the following code that reads through a line of students and the program should split at each white space then go to the next part of the text but I get arrayindexoutofBound exception. 
The text file has several lines like this:

```
130002 Bob    B2123   35   34   B2132   34   54   B2143   23   34



public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Softey\\Documents\\scores.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

    List<MarkProcessing> people = new ArrayList<MarkProcessing>();

    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] details = line.split("\\s+");

        String regNumber = details[0];
        String name = details[1];
        String modOne= details[2];
        int courseM = Integer.parseInt(details[3]);
        int examM = Integer.parseInt(details[4]);
        String modTwo = details[5];
        int courseM2 = Integer.parseInt(details[6]);
        int examM2 = Integer.parseInt(details[7]);
        String modThree = details[8];
        int courseM3 = Integer.parseInt(details[9]);
        int examM3= Integer.parseInt(details[10]);

        MarkProcessing p = new MarkProcessing(regNumber, name, modOne,courseM, examM, modTwo,courseM2,examM2, modThree, courseM3,  examM3);
        people.add(p);
    }


}
```

}

When it goes to details[1] I get the index error.

Comment: Which line causes the exception ?

Comment: Have it check the size of the split array and if it's less than 11, print the line that is messing up.

Comment: Maybe add a file and whole error message?

Comment: It could be because your file has empty lines in it. Try adding a condition like, `if(details.length <= 2) continue;` right after you declare details.

Comment: You really should add a whole lot of exception handling here to make sure you're getting the values out that you expect to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without information regarding the input file, I am going to guess this is because of blank lines in your file. If this is the case, you should try something to ensure that you have enough pieces.. For this, your while loop could be something like this.

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    String[] details = line.split("\\s+");
    if(details.length < 11) continue; // skip this iteration
    ...
}
```

Keep in mind this is only going to work if you are checking at least 11 items per line. If you need a more advanced method of parsing the input, whereas they may have any number of courses. You are better off thinking of another approach than simply storing values directly from indices.

Answer (score 0):

You should try printing the line before parsing it so that you can see what causes it to blow up.

```
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    String[] details = line.split("\\s+");

    String regNumber = details[0];
    String name = details[1];
    String modOne= details[2];
```

You are splitting on chunks of spaces.  In the event you encounter a line with no spaces, then there will only be a single element and therefore `details[1]` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

My suggestion is to examine your input carefully.  Does it have at trailing line feed?  If so, that may be interpreted as a blank line

```
130002 Bob    B2123   35   34   B2132   34   54   B2143   23   34
<blank line>
```

Answer (score -1):

To split by space, you need to use:

```
String[] details = line.split(" "); // "\\s+" -> does not split by space.
```

In your case, it is trying to split the line by the regex pattern '//s+' and since this is not found, it considers the whole line to be one string. In this case, the size of the string array is 1. There is no details[1] and hence you get this error.

Comment: \\s+ splits about any number of spaces. This isn't why.

Comment: see the `\\s+` regex in action here: http://fiddle.re/5pk8j => it matches any number of spaces...